# Pivot wider and summarise whether level exists

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('2021-01-05','2021-01-05','2021-01-10'),
             creature =c('bird','dog','dog'))
```

I'd like to use pivot_wider to create column names for every individual item in `creature`, then populate the dataframe with TRUE or FALSE depending on whether that thing exists for that date or not.

```
 date       creature bird  dog  
  <chr>      <chr>  <lgl> <lgl>
1 2021-01-05 bird   TRUE  TRUE 
2 2021-01-05 dog    TRUE  TRUE 
3 2021-01-10 dog    FALSE TRUE
```

I can do this with dplyr, however, if there were dozens of levels, this would be annoying to do. Is there a way to do this with pivot_wider?

```
df %>% group_by(date) %>% 
      mutate(bird = ifelse('bird' %in% creature,TRUE,FALSE),
             dog = ifelse('dog' %in% creature, TRUE,FALSE))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = creature, id_cols = date, values_from = creature) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(!date, ~!is.na(.x))) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "date")

        date creature  bird  dog
1 2021-01-05     bird  TRUE TRUE
2 2021-01-05      dog  TRUE TRUE
3 2021-01-10      dog FALSE TRUE
```

Check for data with more animals(?)

```
df <- data.frame(date = c('2021-01-05','2021-01-05','2021-01-10', '2021-01-10', '2021-01-11'),
                 creature =c('bird','dog','dog', 'cat', 'dragon'))

df
        date creature
1 2021-01-05     bird
2 2021-01-05      dog
3 2021-01-10      dog
4 2021-01-10      cat
5 2021-01-11   dragon

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = creature, id_cols = date, values_from = creature) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(!date, ~!is.na(.x))) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "date")

        date creature  bird   dog   cat dragon
1 2021-01-05     bird  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
2 2021-01-05      dog  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE
3 2021-01-10      dog FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
4 2021-01-10      cat FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
5 2021-01-11   dragon FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: Why break the `%>%` piping before joining? The id is derived from df to reshape and join back to df, so I don't think there's an occasion when it won't match.

Comment: @thelatemail Now I notice that I can use `right_join`. Thanks a lot :D!

Comment: Or `inner_join`, shouldn't make any difference.